# How do I toggle/collapse a javascript element (I want to collapse the html by default)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I need help with my code to make the below html collapse because it does not collapse currently

This is the javascript function code

```
function(event, ui) {
    html='';
    var show = "Yes";
    html += "<h5 id='collapsible'>"+ show +"</h5>";
};

$('#history').html(html);
```

Here is the html text code to show the Yes on the html page

```
<div id="history"></div>
```

Please help me Toggle/Collapse the `<div id="history"></div>`

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using jQuery, you can simply use `toggle()`:

```
$("#history").toggle();
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution with jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript method for this:

```
function toggle() {
    var target = document.getElementById("history");
    if(target.style.display == 'block'){
        target.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        target.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

To collapse the HTML by default, set the attribute:

```
<div id="history" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Comment: Just remember that it will not hide it if it's something else than `block` (e.g. `inline-block`)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
$('#collapseHistory').on('click', function(){
      $("#history").toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="history" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="collapseHistory">Show/Hide</div>
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery Version**:

http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/xBdkl

```
<div id="temp" onClick="javascript:func()">Show/Hide</div>
<p/>
<div id="history"></div>
<script>
var html='';
 var show = "Yes";
 html += "<h5 id='collapsible'>"+ show +"</h5>";
  $('#history').html(html);

var func = function(){
  if($("#history").is(":visible")){
      $('#history').hide();
  }else{
  $('#history').show();
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `javascript:` in `onclick`, there is no reason for it. 2. A jQuery solution would use `toggle()`, otherwise you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ah, ok, toggle() is a better solution.  Got it!  Mine is a bad one, but a solution nevertheless.  Just saying.